# Some Youtube Videos have no Audio on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Running Raspbian Buster

Tags: audio, pi-4, raspbian-buster, youtube, firefox

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B as my desktop computer with Raspbian Buster installed and everything works great except that some videos on Youtube don't have any audio. If I download the video and play it with Totem, then I can hear the audio. Is there a package that I need to install in order to hear the audio in my browser? I am using firefox-esr.

[image: Video properties in Totem Player]

Comment: Apparently recent versions of  Firefox [won't work](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/firefox-55-0-2-doesnt-start-crashes-on-ubuntu-mate-raspberrypi-3/14637/6) on ARM. You could try installing an ARM64 version, or one of the Firefox clones such as Palemoon/Basilisk. I'll check this out myself on the weekend, meanwhile you can try [this](https://dimagog.ddns.net/share/palemoon-28.8.0a1.linux-gnueabi-armv6.tar.bz2) old build of mine if you like.

Comment: The audio worked within the Palemoon build that you linked to. I'll have to try an ARM64 version of Firefox and see if that works as well. I appreciate you checking this out.

Comment: FIY, I have made a [build](https://dimagog.ddns.net/share/palemoon-28.8.4.linux-gnueabi-armv6.tar.xz) palemoon-28.8.4 from github.com/MoonchildProductions/UXP (the Pale_Moon-release branch). Seems to play youtube just fine. Could you include a link to a video showing the problem?

Comment: This is the video that I am using to test with and it worked fine with your Palemoon build: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Huqll4cGXiE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked your [test video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Huqll4cGXiE) and it works fine in the latest Pale Moon, with sound.

Pale Moon browser is a fork of Firefox which supports older Firefox addons (which Firefox dropped after version 52). It is slower than Chromium but requires significantly less RAM, so it can actually outperform Chromium on a system which is short on memory.

Pale Moon can be installed by following instruction [here](https://linux.palemoon.org/). For the latest Raspbian, the installation instructions are:

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/stevenpusser/Raspbian_10/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:stevenpusser.list
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:stevenpusser/Raspbian_10/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
apt-get update
apt-get install palemoon
```

Answer (score 2):

Try playing the downloaded file with Firefox using File->Open.

If doesn't work, check that you have the AAC codecs installed using `ffmpeg -codecs`.

If playing the local file does work, then, as outlined [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1516178) you should start Firefox with `MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX=1` env variable, or whitelist the directory where the codec libraries are located in, e.g. `security.sandbox.content.read_path_whitelist=/usr/local/lib/`.

Also note that on Raspbian Chromium seems to have better support than Firefox. Apparently, the Firefox ESR build currently available in Raspbian supports none of the settings that are discussed above. So the only option is to use an alternative build of Firefox or a different browser.

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thank you for your response to my question. I tried your suggestions and this was the results:

$ ffmpeg -codecs | egrep -i "aac|264"
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100

Comment: DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m h264_mmal ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_omx h264_v4l2m2m h264_vaapi )
 DEA.L. aac                  AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) (decoders: aac aac_fixed )
 D.A.L. aac_latm             AAC LATM (Advanced Audio Coding LATM syntax)

$ MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX=1 firefox <--- Still no audio

security.sandbox.content.read_path_whitelist <--- Entry not found in about:config

Comment: I do hear audio when using File->Open in firefox, btw.